# Return data when joining two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

1º table - Utente

| codigo | nome |
| --- | --- |
| 105 | teste |
| 206 | teste1 |
| 302 | teste2 |

2º table - MapIncont

| codUte | Dia |
| --- | --- |
| 105 | 3-Noite |
| 105 | 4-SOS |
| 206 | 1-Manhã |
| 206 | 2-Tarde |
| 206 | 3-Noite |
| 206 | 4-SOS |

I intend that if it does not exist in the second table, it will always return the data from the first table. For example, if you do this query, it returns the data:

```
SELECT codigo, nome, codUte
FROM Utente LEFT OUTER JOIN MapIncont ON MapIncont.codUte = Utente.codigo 
WHERE codigo = 206 AND Dia = '1-Manhã'
```

return:

| codigo | nome | codUte |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 206 | teste1 | 206 |

But I want to do the following query:

```
SELECT codigo, nome, codUte
FROM Utente LEFT OUTER JOIN MapIncont ON MapIncont.codUte = Utente.codigo 
WHERE codigo = 105 AND Dia = '1-Manhã'
```

and returns the empty query, like this:

| codigo | nome | codUte |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |

But I want it to return the following data, as shown in the following example:

| codigo | nome | codUte |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 105 | teste |  |

How can I solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WHERE ... Dia = '1-Manhã'
```

excludes all rows that have no match in `MapIncont`, effectively turning your `LEFT OUTER` join into an `INNER` join.

What you want is probably this:

```sql
SELECT codigo, nome, codUte
FROM Utente 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MapIncont 
  ON MapIncont.codUte = Utente.codigo AND Dia = '1-Manhã'
WHERE codigo = 105
```